# Non-cyclical keyboard layout changes in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04, keyboard-layout

How do I use non-cyclical keyboard layout changes in Ubuntu 22?

[image]

I've tried using Gnome-tweaks to no avail.
Using toggle shortcuts works. E.g. if I bind Caps Lock (`grp:caps_toggle` in setxkbmap-speak) it works as expected - cycles through layouts. But when I use `Left Ctrl to first layout; Right Ctrl to last layout` those key combos do nothing.

### What I want:

- press <kbd>key or key combination A</kbd> - get layout A
- press <kbd>key or key combination A</kbd> - no layout change, still layout A
- press <kbd>key or key combination B</kbd> - get layout B

I assume setxkbmap options below (which are selectable in Gnome Tweaks too) are a way to get what I want

```
grp:shift_caps_switch Caps Lock to first layout; Shift+Caps Lock to last layout
grp:win_menu_switch  Left Win to first layout; Right Win/Menu to last layout
grp:lctrl_rctrl_switch Left Ctrl to first layout; Right Ctrl to last layout
grp:lctrl_lwin_rctrl_menu Left Ctrl+Left Win to first layout; Right Ctrl+Menu to second layout
```

Please, help me find the answer

Comment: Assuming you use Ubuntu on Wayland, it's worth mentioning that the XKB way to switch keyboard layout doesn't work well in 22.04. Your observation may be a variant of [this bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1956916).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this bug is something very similar to what I am experiencing. Though people there seem able to fix the symptoms by switching to XORG (instead of Wayland), which does nothing for my problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still searching for a solution that will allow me to use combos like <kbd>Left Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Super</kbd>.

Meanwhile, if you're OK with using a more limited shortcut possibility space, here's a variant solution, using default tools:

**Note**: it will break your default layout cycling.

1. Press Super (win)
2. Type `keyboard`, go to **Keyboard settings**
3. Scroll down, go to **Keyboard shortcuts**
4. Scroll down, go to **Custom shortcuts**
5. Add a custom shortcut

   - Name: anything you like
   - Command: `setxkbmap -layout us` (change `us` to the layout you want)
   - Shortcut: set a shortcut you like
6. Repeat adding shortcuts for as many layouts as you like